# condition sql statement with excel cell reference

Tags: sql, excel, reference, conditional-statements, cell

I am applying some SQL query into a spreadsheet, and have trouble to minimize number of worksheets/connections.

i have 3 scenarios, for each of them, I use same query

```
 select *
 from ***scenario_table***
 where mycolumn > 100
```

Now I have to do this three times for different "scenario_table", and I really wanna to use a cell as reference (let's say cell $A$1)

I wanna sth like this

```
 select *
 from
     case when [$A$1] = 1 ***scenario1_table***
     case when [$A$1] = 2 ***scenario2_table***
     case when [$A$1] = 3 ***scenario3_table***
  where mycolumn > 100
```

my I know whether there is any way to work it out?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you have SQL query? List, pivot table, just statement text...?

Comment: excel -> data -> from other sources -> from MS query

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Assuming your cell with content is in `Sheet1!A1` and there is only one conecction in your workbook, insert following code in `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Then
        Select Case Me.Range("A1").Value
            Case 1: SetTable ("Scenary1_Table")
            Case 2: SetTable ("Scenary2_Table")
            Case 3: SetTable ("Scenary3_Table")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub SetTable(ByVal TableName As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections(1)
        .ODBCConnection.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, I have multiple connections in my workbook.

Comment: Ok, if you can define it, instead of `Connections(1)`, we can choose correct one.